# Simple idea to align paragraphs to a baseline grid

Tags: positioning, multicol, grid-typesetting

**The idea** was to save the vertical position right after beginning the multi columns and then count from that position the next suitable position whenever there is need to align a text paragraph to a baseline grid row.

**Problem** is that after playing with the values (pt and sp) I somehow couldn't accomplish what I wanted. It doesn't seem to be enough to just adjust the *gridrowheight* length and other values (font size, linespacing and parskip) so that paragraphs on both sides would be fully aligned to the baseline grid; vertical spaces get added to certain positions, but their height is not precisely what they should be.

I think the problem has something to do with the position values. I feel like I'm missing something here, but at the moment I'm not sure what it is.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{intcalc}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\usepackage[colaction]{multicol}
\geometry{a4paper}
\geometry{portrait}
\geometry{top=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm}

\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

\newlength\textstartypos
\newlength\vspacedistance
%\newlength\tempval

\newcommand{\settextstartypos}[1]{
\zsavepos{#1}
\setlength\textstartypos{\the\dimexpr\zposy{#1}sp}
%\the\dimexpr\zposy{#1}sp
}

\newlength\gridrowheight
%\addtolength\gridrowheight{40pt}
\addtolength\gridrowheight{1706432sp}

\newcommand{\skiptonextypos}[1] {
\zsavepos{#1}
\setlength\vspacedistance{\textstartypos}
\addtolength\vspacedistance{-\the\dimexpr\zposy{#1}sp}
\setlength\vspacedistance{\intcalcMod{\vspacedistance}{\gridrowheight}sp}
%\setlength\tempval{\intcalcMod{\vspacedistance}{\gridrowheight}sp}
\setlength\vspacedistance{\intcalcSub{\gridrowheight}{\vspacedistance}sp}
\vspace{\vspacedistance}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{spacing}{1.0}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\settextstartypos{textstartypos}
\lipsum[2]

\skiptonextypos{someposition1}
\lipsum[3]

\lipsum[4]

\skiptonextypos{someposition2}
\lipsum[5]

\skiptonextypos{someposition3}
\lipsum[6]
\end{multicols}
\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

[image: not quite aligned]

Comment: One problem is the "LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right." The positions are stored in the aux-file when the page is written. In the next run you are using this values to change the positions -- but this naturally change the positions again. So you never reach a stable state.